# How to prevent window shrinking after a particular width and height in uwp

Tags: xaml, uwp, universal

I am working on *uwp* application and want to make it responsive. For that I have to prevent the window from shrinking after a certain width and height. Is there any way to do so?I have already used setpreferredminsize attribute but it is not working.
`

```
<Page
        x:Class="Inventory.UWP.AuthenticatePage"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="using:Inventory.UWP"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls"
        xmlns:extensions="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Extensions"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" KeyDown="Page_KeyDown">


        <Grid ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
            <Grid Margin="0" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  >
                <Grid.Background>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="login_backg.png" />
                </Grid.Background>

                <StackPanel Background="#FCF9F9" BorderBrush="#C1BFBF" BorderThickness="1" Height="411" Width="664" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" >

                    <!--Header Image-->
                    <Image Source="login_header.png"  Stretch="Uniform"  />


                    <StackPanel Margin="-1,0,-1,0" Padding="0,0,0,0" Height="89"   >
                        <Grid Height="88">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="22*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="53*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <!--UserName and User TextBox-->
                            <TextBlock  FontFamily="{StaticResource inventoryBoldFont}" FontSize="14"  Text="Username" Margin="81,36,43,33" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  />

                            <Border Height="37" Width="341" Grid.Column="1" CornerRadius="5"   BorderBrush="#C1BFBF" BorderThickness="0.5" Margin="1,20,77,19"  >
                                <TextBox  BorderThickness="0"  Name="username" Text="" TextChanging="UsernameErrorMessageClear" Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
                            </Border>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"  Name="UserNameError"  FontSize="12" Foreground="red" Margin="26,62,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  />


                        </Grid>
                    </StackPanel>


                    <StackPanel Margin="-1,0,9,0" Padding="0,0,0,0" Height="89"   >
                        <Grid Height="90">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="22*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="53*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <!--Password and User TextBox-->
                            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  Grid.Row="0" FontFamily="{StaticResource inventoryBoldFont}" FontSize="14"  Text="Password"  Width="57" Margin="81,31,54,40" />

                            <Border Margin="27,19,94,34" Height="37" Width="341" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" CornerRadius="5" BorderBrush="#C1BFBF" BorderThickness="0.5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
                                <PasswordBox Margin="0" BorderThickness="0" Name="userPassword"  Password="" IsPasswordRevealButtonEnabled ="True" PasswordChanging="UserPassword_PasswordChanging"  />
                            </Border>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Name="passwordError" FontSize="12" Foreground="red" Margin="27,58,47,0" />
                        </Grid>
                    </StackPanel>

                    <!--Login Button-->
                    <Button Width="228" Height="37" Content="LOGIN" FontSize="14" Foreground="White"  FontWeight="Medium" Style="{StaticResource LoginBtnStyle }" Click="AuthenticateUser" Name="LoginBtn" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"  UseSystemFocusVisuals="True"  PointerEntered="LoginBtn_PointerEntered" PointerExited="LoginBtn_PointerExited"></Button>

                    <!--Forget passwod link-->
                    <HyperlinkButton  Foreground="#414042" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"  >
                        <HyperlinkButton.ContentTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock FontSize="12" FontFamily="{StaticResource inventoryRegularFont}" Text="Forgot your password?" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </HyperlinkButton.ContentTemplate>
                    </HyperlinkButton>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Page>
```

`
I have given my front end code above. Please check this.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to limit the min window width?

Comment: yes...because the window allows me to shrink it more which cuts my controls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to limit the min window Size, you could use [`SetPreferredMinSize`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationview.setpreferredminsize#Windows_UI_ViewManagement_ApplicationView_SetPreferredMinSize_Windows_Foundation_Size_) method to limit.

```
ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().SetPreferredMinSize(
   new Size(
       300, // Width
       300 // Height
       )
   );
```

Please note

> To remove the preferred minimum size and use and system default minimum size instead, set the Size value to "0,0".
>
> The smallest allowed minimum size is 192 x 48 effective pixels. The largest allowed minimum size is 500 x 500 effective pixels. If you set a value outside of these bounds, it is coerced to be within the allowed bounds. (To learn about effective pixels, see Responsive design 101 for .)

Comment: i used this in my code..but still it is allowing me to shrink the window below the specified size.

Comment: Could you share your page xaml?

Comment: i got the answer.., uwp doesn't allow us for a minimum window size which is greater then 500*500 and i was using the window size greater than this.